# Function to read values from a worksheet by providing path

Tags: vba, excel

I want to populate some cells with values from another workbook. To accomplish this, I wrote a function that will take the name of a person as parameter, which will be the name of the file to open and read information from.

To simplify, let's assume that there's only one person.

The worksheet that calls the function is located at

```
C:\Dados\People
```

And the files I want to read from are located at

```
C:\Dados\People\Projects
```

This is the code I have so far, to simply echo the value of a cell that's store on the first worksheet:

```
Public Function TipoProjeto(name As String) As String
Dim shAux As Worksheet

shAux = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Dados\People\Projects\person1.xlsx").Sheets(sheet1)

MsgBox shAux.Range("B2").Value

TipoProjeto = "test"
End Function
```

I set a breakpoint for the MsgBox instruction, but I cannot get past the open instruction. What can I be missing?

Comment: Are you calling this from a cell? If so, it won't work.

Comment: Try `Set shAux = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Dados\People\Projects\person1.xlsx").Sheets("sheet1")`

Comment: Try to use this -> `Set shAux `

Comment: For future reference, providing details of the error you are getting definitely helps.  The first issue I can see is that you are trying to set an object reference without the `Set` keyword in place as @Vityata has suggested.

Comment: yes I am @Rory . Is there an alternative way to do this from a cell?

Comment: @Dave I tried to use the `Set` keyword and setting the sheet name between quotation marks with no luck. When I call the function from a cell, the cell gets `#VALUE!`

Comment: what exactly are you hoping to archive when using the  `=TipoProjeto()` function? Do you want to find a string related to the string in the function?

Comment: @VBAPete the `TipoProjeto` function receives a string that will match a file on the  `C:\Dados\People\Projects` folder. Let's say `TipoProjeto("VBAPete")` will search for a file named `VBAPete.xlsx` and then output the value of cell B2

Comment: I can't find anything on opening workbooks using a function. There might be limitation of what you can use inside of a function.

Comment: You can't open a workbook from a UDF. Google Harlan coben's Pull function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Workbook object and not worksheet object at the beginning.
The below will work:

```
Public Function TipoProjeto() As String
Dim location As String
location = "C:\Dados\People\Projects\person1.xlsx"

Dim wkb As Workbook
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open(location)

Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = wkb.sheets("Sheet1") 'Use set sht = wkb.sheet1 only if the sheet has been named this in the project explorer

MsgBox sht.Range("B2").Value

TipoProjeto = "test"

End Function
```